# Posterior Probability python example

Tags: python, statistics, bayesian

I've been building a simple Approximate Bayes Calculation application and ran into a problem. I don't know how to properly implement [posterior probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability).

My prior: non-informative (uniform distribution)

Generative model: random yes/no guessing implemented using numpy binomial distribution

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def pprob():
    pass

def generative_model(n_events, p):
    return np.random.binomial(n_events, p)

def ABC(n_occured, n_events, n_draws=100000):
    prior = pd.Series(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n_draws))
    sim_data = [generative_model(n_events, p) for p in prior]
    posterior = prior[list(map(lambda x: x == n_occured, sim_data))]
    posterior_probability = pprob()

ABC(10, 16)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

thanks: [this site](https://www.datascience.com/blog/introduction-to-bayesian-inference-learn-data-science-tutorials)

full code of my solution was:

```
import math
from scipy import stats
from scipy.special import factorial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def likelihood(theta, n, x):
    return (factorial(n) / (factorial(x) * factorial(n - x))) * (theta  x) * ((1 - theta)  (n - x))

def pprob(prior, posterior, n_occured, n_events):
    return pd.Series(map(lambda theta: likelihood(theta, n_events, n_occured), prior))

def generative_model(n_events, p):
    return np.random.binomial(n_events, p)

def ABC(n_occured, n_events, n_draws=1000):
    prior = pd.Series(sorted(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n_draws)))
    sim_data = [generative_model(n_events ,p) for p in prior]
    posterior = prior[list(map(lambda x: x == n_occured, sim_data))]
    posterior_probability = pprob(prior, posterior, n_occured, n_events)

    # let's see what we got
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.plot(prior, posterior_probability)
    ax.set_xlabel("Theta")
    ax.set_ylabel("Likelihood")
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_title("Likelihood of Theta for New Campaign")
    plt.show()

ABC(10, 16)
```

produces me this cute likelihood:

[image: [a]]

Comment: The sited source in this post has changed. It can be found [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/ai-and-datascience/post/introduction-to-bayesian-inference)

Answer (score 0):

I added a few corrections so it would work first time:

```
import math
from scipy import stats
from scipy.special import factorial
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def likelihood(theta, n, x):
    return (factorial(n) / (factorial(x) * factorial(n - x))) * (theta ** x) * ((1 - theta) ** (n - x))

def pprob(prior, posterior, n_occured, n_events):
    return pd.Series(map(lambda theta: likelihood(theta, n_events, n_occured), prior))

def generative_model(n_events, p):
    return np.random.binomial(n_events, p)

def ABC(n_occured, n_events, n_draws=1000):
    prior = pd.Series(sorted(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=n_draws)))
    sim_data = [generative_model(n_events ,p) for p in prior]
    posterior = prior[list(map(lambda x: x == n_occured, sim_data))]
    posterior_probability = pprob(prior, posterior, n_occured, n_events)

    # let's see what we got
    f, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    ax.plot(prior, posterior_probability)
    ax.set_xlabel("Theta")
    ax.set_ylabel("Likelihood")
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_title("Likelihood of Theta for New Campaign")
    plt.show()

ABC(10, 16)
```